# LinearLayout with adaptable wrapping of TextView

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm struggling to refine a `ListView` row item which has three specific width columns.

Column A has a `Button` and vertical divider `View`

Column B has a `TextView` and may or may not have an `ImageView` showing next to it depending on circumstances

Column C has `RelativeLayout` that can show nothing, or a `TextView`, `CheckBox` or `ImageView` depending on circumstances

See example image. The Herring Gull row doesn't need an icon. The Herring x Lesser Black-backed Gull (hybrid) needs a red icon, similar to the other species above and below it. However, the longer species name is pushing the icon out of view when it wraps onto two lines.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/species_row_container"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
          android:orientation="horizontal">


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_count"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.15"
    android:background="@null"
    android:paddingBottom="3dp"
    android:paddingTop="3dp"
    android:text="+"
    android:textColor="@color/light_gray"/>

<View
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:background="@color/bpWhite"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="3dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.70">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_species_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:minHeight="44dp"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:text="Species name"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="15sp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/speciesBinIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingStart="5dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_uncommon"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.10"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_rare"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rare_border"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/single_character_for_rare"
        android:textColor="@color/rareBackground"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:buttonTint="@color/rareBackground"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/high_count_warning"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_high_count"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have tried replacing the `TextView` & `ImageView` combination with a single `TextView` populated with a `SpannableStringBuilder`, but that positioned the icon at the end of the wrapped text (see example with Green Woodpecker), when I'd like it positioned to the right of the text.

[image]

My desired behaviour is for the `ImageView` icon to always be right next to the `TextView`, and when the `TextView` is long, the `ImageView` becomes dominant within Column B and the `TextView` wraps it's text into a slightly smaller space.

Is this possible please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the `ImageView` with the icon and add an icon directly to the `TextView` if you want to show it with the following line of code:

```
textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.your_id, 0);
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

it is hard to understand from your question completely , but what i've decoded is you require to place *textview* and *imageview* side by side that can only be possible if you hardcode textview width and give textview height as **match_paren**t , something like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/species_row_container"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
          android:orientation="horizontal">


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_count"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.15"
    android:background="@null"
    android:paddingBottom="3dp"
    android:paddingTop="3dp"
    android:text="+"
    android:textColor="@color/light_gray"/>

<View
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:background="@color/bpWhite"/>

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="3dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.90">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview_species_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:toStartOf="@+id/speciesBinIcon"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:minHeight="44dp"
                android:paddingBottom="3dp"
                android:paddingTop="3dp"
                android:text="Species name"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="15sp"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/speciesBinIcon"
                android:alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingStart="5dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_uncommon"
                android:visibility="gone"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.10"
            android:gravity="center_vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview_rare"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:background="@drawable/rare_border"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/single_character_for_rare"
                android:textColor="@color/rareBackground"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:visibility="gone"/>

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkbox"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:buttonTint="@color/rareBackground"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:visibility="gone"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/high_count_warning"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_high_count"
                android:visibility="gone"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**P.S:** code is not tested it is just a general idea

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare a maxWidth for your textView         `android:id="@+id/textview_species_name"`
 in order to make it work properly. Keep in mind that it has to be dynamic based on device's screen width